# Adding title text inside gauge Dojo

Tags: svg, dojo, gauge, dojox.gfx

i need to insert a title (not a tooltip, a text on the top) inside the svg rendered by Dojo. How can i do that?

Here my Dgauge:
http://jsfiddle.net/MacroX/pZU93/1/

PD: The line

```
gauge.title = 'Test Report'
```

doesnt show the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a way to resolve this, and this is useful when you need to personalize your dgauge. Here the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/MacroX/THJqV/

What i did is basicly create a gauge, fill it with background white, and then add elements inside

```
var baseWidth = 400;
gauge.addElement("background", function (g) {
    var auxHeight = baseWidth * objGauge.offsetHeight / objGauge.offsetWidth;
    g.createRect({
        width: 400, height: auxHeight
        //width: 400, height: 300
    }).setFill("#FFF");
});
```

I dont know if is the best way, but works and i didnt find something similar in other sites

And what I think is great, this support multiple chart dgauges in only one SVG

I hope this will useful to someone else

Comment: Your question was not very clear from the beginning. You never mentioned multiple gauges. You did in fact end up using a `TextIndicator` like I mentioned; you just used `value` and moved the `x` and `y` values to display it above the gauges.

Comment: Multiple gauges was a new requirement. Of course I use what you say, but the problem with your answer was I needed the title on the top, not inside the gauge, so I have to find a way to move the gauge, and that was I finally did

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** The question is regarding a label at the top of the gauge, not the `title` attribute as I originally thought.

You can use a `TextIndicator` much like you did for the value label below the needle, but you can set a `labelFunc` property that defines a function called to set a label and displays whatever string is returned from it.

```
var labelText = new TextIndicator();
labelText.set('x', 73.3);
labelText.set('y', 55);
labelText.set('labelFunc', function() {return 'Test Report';});
gauge.addElement('labelText', labelText);
```

[Here is a modified version of your fiddle with the title text in place](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/RtT5z/).

---

<sup>Original answer remans below in case someone else needs it</sup>

Pass the `title` in when you create the gauge:

```
var gauge = new CircularLinearGauge({
    title: 'Test Report'
}, dojo.byId("gauge"));
```

You can also use `set` to set it after the gauge is created:

```
gauge.set('title', 'Test Report'); //does work :)
```

---

The reason for this is that the gauge widget needs to set the text you give as the `title` on a specific element within the widget's template. `gauge.title` just sets the `title` property of the gauge widget, and the widget has no idea when or with what value that property is being set and thus is not able to make it show up as a title attribute on the gauge.

Comment: mmm I think I was not clear, I dont need a tooltip, I need a text on the top of the graphic as a title. I was thinking in create an empty component and then add elements there like in the prev jsfiddle, is that posible? example: replacing `var gauge = new CircularLinearGauge({}, dojo.byId("gauge"));` for `var gauge = new EmptyGauge({width:400,height:400}, dojo.byId("gauge"));`

Comment: I've updated my answer with something more along the lines of what I believe you wanted.

Comment: your answer is helpful, but is not exactly what i need. Actually, I find a way and I will mark this as an answer for other people who have this problem. Thanks anyway